# Excel VBA - Paste from clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a macro that looks like this:

```
Sub CopyAsValues()
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

It seems to me that Excel requires from me to add a copy line, e.g.:

```
Range("C1:C5").Copy"
```

But I don't want to. I want to manually copy from cells, and then use the macro to paste as values. How can I do that?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/paste-clipboard-contents-vba/) article. It should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Why would you use a macro when Alt+E, S, V <enter> does the trick? Better yet, assign *Paste Values* to the QAT: see [Is there a way to autofill cells in Excel 2013 with keyboard shortcuts](http://superuser.com/questions/840143/is-there-a-way-to-autofill-cells-in-excel-2013-with-keyboard-shortcuts/840169#840169) for my own Paste Values solution.

Comment: @Peter: I've read that article, but it didn't really help me.. Do you think I should try harder? ;)

Comment: @Jeeped: Alt+E, S, V <enter> is uncomfortable for me. I wanted a simpler shortcut. But maybe I could try the QAT way :)

Comment: Better shortcut in my opinion : `CTRL + ALT + V` = PasteSpecial menu, then just double click on `Values`
Or you'll have to work with the ClipBoard directly, but I really don't see the point of a macro to paste as values...

Comment: I went for @Jeeped's solution - setting for QAT and then Alt+1 is fast enought for me :)

Comment: For anyone that actually wants to paste from the clipboard check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60802845/vba-paste-clipboard-content-only-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need macro for this,  comfortable way to paste only values, I guess, will be using quick access toolbar as in picture below

Excel Option ~~> Customize ~~> Choose commands from [All Commands] ~~> Select "Paste Values" command and add to toolbar

[image]

so you will receive button in top of the excel window with required option

[image]

then you can copy and paste only values using this button