# VBA Paste clipboard content (only value)

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I'm trying to paste clipboard content to cell "A1"

```
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

But I get "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed" error!

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What "only value" does mean? Can you show us an example? Not a formula, looking to your PasteSpecial parameter...?

Comment: What happens when you try `Range("A1").PasteSpecial Format:="Text"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test this code, please (it works only for text clipboard type):

```
Sub testClipB()
 Dim CB As Object
 Set CB = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
 CB.GetFromClipboard
 Range("A1").value = CB.GetText
End Sub
```

Or this one:

```
Sub testPasteClipB_Bis()
    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard

    Range("A2").value = DataObj.GetText(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Should I understand that it works, but you would like something more? If yes, what else would you like to accomplish?

Comment: That's fine, Thank you. I just needed to paste clipboard content (string) into a cell!

Comment: @Afshin Davoudy: No problem. When I asked about your satisfaction, I head in mind that my both codes are appropriate for clipboard keeping strings **from other application**. If you try taking from clipboard a string being input from Excel, it must be a native more appropriate way... This will only a workaround.

Comment: First option worked for me

Answer (score 1):

### Paste only Values from Selection

**Error**

Run-time error '1004':

PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

**Fact**

`xlPasteValues` is exclusively used after (contents of) **cells** have been **copied** (into the clipboard).

**Problem**

The error always occurs after no cells have been copied or cells have been cut.

**Solution**

Therefore you should check (test) `CutCopyMode` appropriately and your formula will be fine:

```
Sub PSpec()
     If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
         Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     End If
End Sub
```